# Split Button with Default design

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a split button that looks like the default button, but every time I remove the border to create the split button, the arrow button loses its styling.

So, I want it to look like this: [image: want]

But instead, I am getting this: [image: get]

What am I missing? Here's the code:

```js
.splitbtn-group {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 24px;
    }
    
    .splitbtn {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        left: 20px;
        height: 24px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: ButtonFace;
        color: ButtonText;
        border: 2px outset ButtonFace;
    }
    
    .splitbtn.splitbtn-drop {
        border-left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="splitbtn-group">
        <button class="splitbtn splitbtn-main" data-bind=""> Assign Vaccines</button>
        <button class="splitbtn splitbtn-drop" data-bind="">&#9660;</button>
        <ul class="splitbtn-drop-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Assign Vaccines</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Unassign Vaccines</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default style of a button elements varies by browsers and operating systems, as the case with all the form elements.

The default styling in your case is given by the browser, from what I can see it seems to be Chrome, so if you apply any CSS to the buttons it will fallback to the default OS styling.

Though in your case the buttons style is changed to an even different one. I found out that it is because it only contains non-ASCII.

Adding a span with a white-space seems to be working with it (will also work without the span, just enter a space.)

```
<button class="splitbtn splitbtn-drop" data-bind="">&#9660; <span> </span></button>
```

Anyways the default styling is changed to the default OS style, in my case Windows 8.

Use custom CSS styles to make it look like the default:

```
.splitbtn {
    background-color: ButtonFace;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
     border: 1px outset #999;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc, #fff);
}
```

Do remember to use vendor prefixes for other browsers as well for the `background-image` property and also change `background: ButtonFace;` to `background-color: ButtonFace;`

You have to style the buttons completely in order to make it consistent. Else the inconsistency between the browser's and OS' default styling would persist.

Here's a demo with full code:

```css
.splitbtn-group {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
}


.splitbtn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: ButtonFace;
    color: ButtonText;
    border: 2px outset ButtonFace;
  
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #999;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc, #fff);
}

.splitbtn.splitbtn-drop {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

```html
  <div class="splitbtn-group">
    <button class="splitbtn splitbtn-main" data-bind=""> Assign Vaccines</button>
  <button class="splitbtn splitbtn-drop" data-bind="">&#9660;<span> </span></button>
```

Comment: This works perfectly in Chrome, unfortunately I am running it in a specific application that is built upon IE 8 (I think), and I wasn't able to reproduce it in IE (the borders become square and the gradient doesn't come out right either)...

Comment: You have to use vendor prefixes in order to make the linear work in other browser as I stated in the answer, check Gradient Generator by ColorZilla for easily obtaining CSS that works on most browsers. 

Also you may use `border-radius` if you want to make the borders curved.

Comment: While border-radius doesn't work in IE8, and the space/span didn't make any difference, I ended up using the solution with the gradients at least for now, so I marked this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just give:

```
border-style: solid;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. I made a codePen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqRaqe

Comment: @adinutzyc21 Try the updated one. `outset` is not supported!

Comment: I guess I can't get closer than that...

I changed my `.splitbtn` to `background: rgb(226, 226, 226);  border: 1px solid rgb(166, 163, 163);`